# WP7 - Prevent RestSharp from caching

Tags: windows-phone-7, restsharp

I use RestSharp in my Windows Phone 7.1 project.

My problem is RestSharp always cache response data.

Example:

At the first time I send request, it returns data correctly. After some delete operations, I send that request again, but response seems the same as the first time, nothing's changed.

If I stop debugging and press F5 to start again, it works perfectly as expected.

I also tried `request.AddParameter("cache-control", "no-cache", ParameterType.HttpHeader);` and got no luck.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: RestSharp doesn't have any built-in caching so this is probably in the HttpWebRequest layer it's built on. Do you have control over the API endpoint? Can you post more of your code?

Comment: its a hack but try something like `url = originalUrl + "&nocache=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks`

Comment: I used a similar solution that @RicoSuter mentions to solve an identical problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution in Rico Suter comment, thanks! I will mark this as accepted anwser

> its a hack but try something like url = originalUrl + "&nocache=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks

Comment: Like Rico says, that is a hack... but a working one! Still, I'm curious if you tryed to use "Cache-Control" and add the "Pragma" header too!

Comment: Can we emphasize that this has nothing to do with RestSharp?

Comment: Yes, the problem lies in the `HttpWebRequest` implementation which uses a cache which cannot be disabled...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it has nothing to do with the client, and everything to do with the server.

Comment: Of course if you can modify the server you can disable the cache (see answer from pedro)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue so just add header that specify not to cache response data
client is my RestClient with base url and than add default header Cache-Control with value no-cache.

```
client.AddDefaultHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Cache-Control" header should do the trick!

I think HTTP Headers are case-insensitive, but the server may not agree with me there! You should try using `Cache-Control` instead of `cache-control`...

Also, I would also add the `Pragma` header with `no-cache` value to the request (some old servers don't use the "Cache-Control" header, but they will sure recognize this one)!

And I would try to use Fiddler to debug the comms and check that the headers are really being sent to the server as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be to set the "If-Modified-Since" header with value of `DateTime.Now`:

```
client.AddDefaultParameter("If-Modified-Since", DateTime.Now, ParameterType.HttpHeader);
```